# Forma correcta de mostrar dinero

Tags: java, bigdecimal, java-money

Estoy comenzando a trabajar en un sistema que administra dinero, para los montos ocupo el tipo de dato BigDecimal, sin embargo me he encontrado con algunos problemas al momento de generar facturas para el cliente final, pues las facturas solamente tienen 2 decimales, por lo tanto:

Si un producto cuesta $ 1.004 y el cliente compra 300 piezas de este producto el costo real será de $ 301.2  pero en la factura el cliente verá lo siguiente:

cantidad : 300

costo unitario : $ 1.00

total : $ 301.20

El cliente al verlo pensará que es un error.

La manera en la que muestro los datos es la siguiente :

```
    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(getTotal());

    System.out.println(Math.round(total.doubleValue() * 100) / 100);
```

Esto me genera 3 principales inquietudes:

- ¿Qué es lo que debería hacerse en ese tipo de casos?
- ¿Cuando se trata de dinero lo correcto es redondear o truncar?(Si es que alguna de estás es una solución correcta)
- ¿Existe algún tipo de dato o librería que se para uso exclusivo de dinero y que tal vez sea mejor a usar BigDecimal?

PD: El ejemplo de arriba es solo un ejemplo simplificado para ayudar a entender el problema real.

Comment: Que código has intentado para resolverlo, un number format le da el formato de salida? o como lo realizas.

Comment: @Ajeno actualizaré la pregunta para añadir esos detalles

Comment: @Ajeno acabo de actualizarlo

Comment: Creo que es por que tu mismo lo estas redondeando.... Tu BigDecimal ya tiene los valores intenta un total.toString()

Comment: @Ajeno Pero eso me va a imprimir todas las decimales y solo debo imprimir 2, ¿Recomiendas truncar o redondear?

Comment: Para multiplicar un BigDecimal por un entero y no perder dígitos por precisión deberias utilizar el metodo multiply() de dicha clase. De lo contrario, si haces doubleValue()*100 vas tener la precisión de un double. Te recomiendo que leas https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html y los distintos modos de redondeo.

Comment: Creo que tus dudas son respondidas aquí: [Java best practices: Representing money](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para representar valores monetarios se recomienda usar:

- [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html): es el valor predeterminado recomendado. Es un poco más incómodo de usar, pero tiene incorporado los modos de redondeo.
- `int`
- `long`

Para decidir cuál de los tres usar, es importante tener en cuenta el número de dígitos que manejará la aplicación (más o menos).

Si número de dígitos:

- `<=9` : usar `BigDecimal`, `int`, o `long`
- `<=18`: usar `BigDecimal` o `long`
- `>18` : usar solamente `BigDecimal`

Cabe señalar que la clase [`Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) encapsula identificadores estándar para las monedas del mundo.

Para representar valores monetarios, **no** se recomienda usar:

- `double`
- `float`

porque siempre llevan [pequeñas diferencias de redondeo](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=213).

---

Algunas cosas a tomar en cuenta con respecto a `BigDecimal`:

- El constructor recomendado es `BigDecimal (String)`, no <s>`BigDecimal (double)`</s> - ver [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) (Cuando se usa el constructor `double` los resultados pueden ser impredecibles).
- Los objetos `BigDecimal` son inmutables: las operaciones siempre devuelven objetos nuevos y nunca modifican el estado de los objetos existentes
- El estilo [`ROUND_HALF_EVEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN) de redondeo introduce el sesgo mínimo. También se llama el redondeo de los banqueros, o redondo-a-igualar.

---

#### Ejemplo de código:

He aquí un ejemplo de código de cálculos monetarios usando `BigDecimal`. El ejemplo está tomado tal cual de su [fuente](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13). Realiza operaciones básicas: `+, - , * , /` entre dos valores.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Currency;

/**
* Example of typical calculations with monetary values, implemented with
* <tt>BigDecimal</tt>.
*
* <P>This example is for a currency which has two decimal places.
*
* See
* http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
*
* Note in particular how the <em>default</em> scale of the result of an
* operation is calculated from the scales of the two input numbers :
* <ul>
* <li> a + b : max[ scale(a), scale(b) ]
* <li> a - b : max[ scale(a), scale(b) ]
* <li> a * b : scale(a) + scale(b)
* <li> a / b : scale(a) - scale(b)
* </ul>
*/
public final class MoneyCalculation {

  /**
  * Simple test harness.
  *
  * Takes two numeric arguments, representing monetary values, in a form
  * which can be passed successfully to the <tt>BigDecimal(String)</tt>
  * constructor (<tt>25.00, 25.0, 25</tt>, etc).
  *
  * Note that the <tt>String</tt> constructor is preferred for
  * <tt>BigDecimal</tt>.
  */
  public static void main(String... aArgs){
    BigDecimal amountOne = new BigDecimal(aArgs[0]);
    BigDecimal amountTwo = new BigDecimal(aArgs[1]);
    MoneyCalculation calc = new MoneyCalculation(amountOne, amountTwo);
    calc.doCalculations();
  }

  public MoneyCalculation(BigDecimal aAmountOne, BigDecimal aAmountTwo){
    fAmountOne = rounded(aAmountOne);
    fAmountTwo = rounded(aAmountTwo);
  }

  public void doCalculations() {
    log("Amount One: " + fAmountOne);
    log("Amount Two: " + fAmountTwo);
    log("Sum : " + getSum());
    log("Difference : " + getDifference());
    log("Average : " + getAverage());
    log("5.25% of Amount One: " + getPercentage());
    log("Percent Change From Amount One to Two: " + getPercentageChange());
  }

  // PRIVATE

  private BigDecimal fAmountOne;
  private BigDecimal fAmountTwo;

  /**
  * Defined centrally, to allow for easy changes to the rounding mode.
  */
  private static int ROUNDING_MODE = BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN;

  /**
  * Number of decimals to retain. Also referred to as "scale".
  */
  private static int DECIMALS = 2;
  //An alternate style for this value :
  //private static int DECIMAL_PLACES =
  //  Currency.getInstance("USD").getDefaultFractionDigits()
  //;

  private static int EXTRA_DECIMALS = 4;
  private static final BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal("2");
  private static BigDecimal HUNDRED = new BigDecimal("100");
  private static BigDecimal PERCENTAGE = new BigDecimal("5.25");

  private void log(String aText){
    System.out.println(aText);
  }

  private BigDecimal getSum(){
    return fAmountOne.add(fAmountTwo);
  }

  private BigDecimal getDifference(){
    return fAmountTwo.subtract(fAmountOne);
  }

  private BigDecimal getAverage(){
    return getSum().divide(TWO, ROUNDING_MODE);
  }

  private BigDecimal getPercentage(){
    BigDecimal result = fAmountOne.multiply(PERCENTAGE);
    result = result.divide(HUNDRED, ROUNDING_MODE);
    return rounded(result);
  }

  private BigDecimal getPercentageChange(){
    BigDecimal fractionalChange = getDifference().divide(
      fAmountOne, EXTRA_DECIMALS, ROUNDING_MODE
    );
    return rounded(fractionalChange.multiply(HUNDRED));
  }

  private BigDecimal rounded(BigDecimal aNumber){
    return aNumber.setScale(DECIMALS, ROUNDING_MODE);
  }
}
```

---

Para más detalles: [Java Best Practices: Representing money](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13)

---

#### Una clase `Money`

Durante años la comunidad de programadores echaba de menos una clase `Money` que ayudase a manejar situaciones como estas.

**Finalmente, el JDK 9 trae incorporada la [API Money](http://javamoney.github.io) en el [JSR 354](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr354/index.html)**, para manejar modelos de dinero y de monedas.

Ver:

- [Especificación de la API Money](http://javamoney.github.io/api.html)
- [Referencia de Implementación (RI)](http://javamoney.github.io/ri.html)
- [Repositorio de Github](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-tck)