# ¿Como puedo pasar una cadena de String a decimal?

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito pasar una cadena de String que esta en un objeto de tipo JTextField a una variable BigDecimal o a cualquier otro tipo de dato que pueda almacenar valores de este tipo "785.292,90" y luego guardalas en la BD (decimal(65,0)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí])

Comment: Sugiero que [leas esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93015/29967), sobre todo si se trata de datos monetarios, como parece ser el caso.

Comment: En esa respuesta no resuelves su duda que es como parsear un string a BigDecimal ("o a cualquier otro tipo de dato que pueda almacenar valores de este tipo"). Tu respuesta trata de cómo representar datos monetarios.

Comment: De verdad que aun no he logrado. Supongo que necesito hacer un casteo pero se pierde precisión

Answer (score 0):

No se puede usar operadores como '/' o '*' con objetos, por ejemplo BigDecimal. Si quieres hacer operaciones has de usar los metodos que ofrece la clase. Por ejemplo:

```
 BigDecimal p = new BigDecimal("123.1231255");
 BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(12.32);
 //el metodo divide solo admite otro BigDecimal en este caso.
 double a = p.divide(d).doubleValue();
```

Si quieres ver una lista completa de los metodos que se pueden usar en la [Documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) aparecen.