# ISO 4217 Existe alguna otra clase aparte de Currency en JAVA?

Tags: java, eclipse

Quiero validar que un codigo introducido existe.
Tengo esto.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String valor = "EUR";
    boolean existe = false;
    for (Currency c : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        if (c.getCurrencyCode().equals(valor)) {
            existe = true;
        } 
    }
    if(!existe) {
        System.out.println("Error, ese código no existe!!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El código si existe!!!");
    }

}
```

Pero al implementarlo al proyecto me da error. (Ya la tengo importada). Existe alguna otra clase para trabajar con esto?.

Comment: Perdón es una prueba que estaba haciendo, pero claro EURA no existe y me me sale que no existe. Pero si es EUR o USD etc, si que me sale. Ese es el objetivo que el cliente me pasará cualquier cosa y yo tengo que comprobar que lo que me introduce existe en la lista ISO.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la duda en concreto? ¿Quieres una alternativa a la clase `Currency` de Java?. Por favor, aclara tu duda. Saludos

Comment: Si saber si existe alguna otra.

Comment: Una forma alternativa de hacer esto es utilizar el método `getInstance()` de `Currency`, pasándole con el código de moneda que te pase el usuario, si te tira una excepción de tipo `IllegalArgumentException` es que el código no es un código ISO4217 válido: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance

Comment: Sii, así lo hice muchas gracias de todas maneras. @ordago

Comment: Probado con el JDK 1.8.0_66, EUR existe y el código funciona bien.

Comment: Desde el JDK 9 existe una API Money, para valores monetarios.  [Ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93015/29967) al final.